# facebook integration in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

i have download code from http://svn.facebook.com/svnroot/platform/clients/packages/fbconnect-iphone.zip

and i done all the thing according to seen in this tutorial 
still get an error when i set path for "projects/FacebookAPI/src" 
like this facebookconnect undeclared still i have include all the things necessarly.
please help me........

This type of error generate in my app.... 
error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos3.1.2'

Please help me.....

Comment: Please check the URL, it appears not to be valid. Can you also detail the error message you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project that you are working with seems to be an older one.
As iOS is updated, newer version of the SDK are released, which don't include the older SDKs. You need to change the SDK version of your project. Right click on the blue project icon in Xcode and click "Get Info". You will want to change the "Base SDK" setting to one of the available options, from 3.1.2.

Try building yur project. If this does not work, right click on your active target (or click Project Settings->Edit Active Target) and change the "Base SDK" there as well.

Try building you project. If this does not work, right click on your project icon in the lefthand panel and click "Reveal in Finder". In Finder, right click on your xcodeproj file and click "Show Package Contents". At this point, I suggest closing Xcode. Open each of the three files and search for "iphoneos3.1.2" if you find it, replace 3.1.2 with the SDK number you want to use (probably 4.2.1). Save the file(s) which you modified and then, if you closed Xcode earlier, open it.

You should be able to build now.

Answer (score 3):

use this blog to the complete facebook integration

http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app